# how to make codeigniter route support small and big for first letter without running 2 difference loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

- All my controller file is start w 1st Big letter.
- my code below if i link to Project/Admin/Career it link to my Career.php
- but if f i link to Project/Admin/career it link to my Admin.php

my question is how do it make $route support both small and big for 1st letter

or i need to duplicated my method_arr to another method_arr1 and run foreach again (with array start small letter ) ?

Ex: Career, career

> ```
> $method_arr=array(
>               'Career',
>               'Contact',
>               'Googlemap',
>               'Introduction',
>               'Slideshow'
>               );
> ```

```
    $route['default_controller'] = "home";

    foreach($method_arr as $method_arr){
        $route['Admin/'.$method_arr] = 'backend/'.$method_arr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In URL's uppercase is distinct from lowercase in millions of ways because of the way it was meant to be unique.

Well you can go about it this way:
    $route['default_controller'] = "home";

```
foreach($method_arr as $method_arr){ 
    $route['Admin/'.strtolower($method_arr)] = 'backend/'.$method_arr;  

$route['Admin/'.$method_arr] = 'backend/'.$method_arr; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the oddity of doing it this way, a simple fix would be to define your routes twice. Using the example you provided you can do this to operate on lowercase or upper case.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";

$method_arr=array(
          'Career',
          'Contact',
          'Googlemap',
          'Introduction',
          'Slideshow'
          );

foreach($method_arr as $method_arr){
    $route['Admin/'.$method_arr] = 'backend/'.$method_arr;
}

$method_arr=array(
          'career',
          'contact',
          'googlemap',
          'introduction',
          'slideshow'
          );

foreach($method_arr as $method_arr){
    $route['Admin/'.$method_arr] = 'backend/'.$method_arr;
}
```